# Где взять цветовую схему для WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

Нужна цветовая схема для webstorm, чтобы цвета были как у редактора Atom. Сам не смог найти, помогите. P.S Atom у меня не открывается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте [Atom OneDark Theme](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12178-atom-onedark-theme), [Atom](http://www.phpstorm-themes.com/theme/atom) или [Atom One Dark Color Scheme](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12311-atom-one-dark-color-scheme)

Comment: Может вы знаете и какой шрифт используется в Atom?

Comment: к сожалению, не знаю:(